# Repo sync fails with "repo is not tracking a remote branch"

Tags: git, android-source, repo, android-soong

When I try to run repo sync I get this error:

```
info: A new version of repo is available warning: repo is not tracking a remote branch, so it will not receive updates repo reset: error: Entry 'git_superproject.py' not uptodate. Cannot merge. fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'v2.16.7^0'.
```

I haven't done any project or repo changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to `.repo/repo/` and run `git status`. If there are any changes, you should run `git checkout -f` to throw them away if you don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.repo/repo` directory entirely, and the next time `repo` runs, it will clone the client again.

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore the info part and look for error messages

```
warning: repo is not tracking a remote branch
```

The local branch is not in sync with remote branch and you can set upstream and use the command to update local

```
 git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> <local-branch>
 git fetch upstream
 git rebase upstream/local-branch
```

For the error and fatal part, you can reset the local branch ignoring the local changes.

```
git reset --hard
```